# Automatic email setup in unix server by script after checking particular logs

Tags: shell-script

I want to send an automatic email from Unix server after checking particular log is running or not.
Every three hours, i want to login in and check X.log and y.log ran or not and taking manaully when it ran. Can anyone help to automate it ?

Comment: you should check about `cron` service to run every three hours... and more details needed for "ran" meant for....

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? The sending an email? Scheduling a task to run every three hours? Checking the log files for particular patterns or sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use below script to check if file exists & set it in cronjob to run it every three hours.

CODE:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LOGNAME="x.log"
export DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%T")
export MAILID="Emailid"


if [[ -e "$LOGNAME" ]];then
        mail -s "$HOSTNAME: is having $LOGNAME on @ $DATE" $MAILID < "$LOGNAME"
else
        mail -s "$HOSTNAME: is not having $LOGNAME on @ $DATE" $MAILID 
fi
```

Setting up in crontab:

```
#crontab -e
```

Add the below lines:

```
* */3 * * *   <path of your script to run>
```

Comment: If this works for you @Maha Can you please accept the answer. For accepting it please follow: meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/

Comment: Your use of `$LOGNAME` overrides a [POSIX reserved variable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html). Generally it's better to use lowercase variables, i.e. `$logname` in this instance